# How to display a randomly generated string (from array) again in another area?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I'm using HTML and JavaScript to make a simple rock, paper, scissors game where a button activates a randomly generated string from an array (rock, paper, or scissors). I already have it so that the button randomly generates a computer choice and it displays my choice (using radio buttons) in a box below. I'm stuck because I don't know how to display the randomly generated computer choice again in another box.

I tried using if else statements but I can't figure out how to reference the randomly chosen string from the array. Here is what I tried before within the html game:

```
<script>
    function myFunction();{
    if (document.getElementById("randomSelect")) = 'rock'{
        document.getElementById('computerChoice').innerHTML = 'rock'
}       if (document.getElementById("randomSelect")) = 'paper'{
        document.getElementById('computerChoice').innerHTML = 'paper'
}       if (document.getElementById("randomSelect")) = 'scissors'{
        document.getElementById('computerChoice').innerHTML = 'scissors'
}
}
</script>
<p id = "computerChoice"></p>
```

Also, sorry if this makes no sense. I'm new to coding.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon edited

Comment: You need to use `==` instead of `=` and also put parentheses around the entire condition.

Comment: And remove the first semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate random number between 0 and 2 (Array Index). Store items in an array and pull out based on random Index generated.

```js
var items = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

    document.getElementById("randomSelect").addEventListener('click', myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
        /*Generate random number between 0 and 2*/
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        /*Set the random Item*/
        document.getElementById('computerChoice').innerHTML = items[randomNum];
    }
```

```html
<p id="computerChoice"></p>
<button type="button" id="randomSelect">Random</button>
```